# How to config wordpress to use sentry performance monitoring?

Tags: php, wordpress, sentry

I'm using Self-Hosted Sentry to monitor my wordpress websites. I receive errors and exceptions log in my sentry host panel and monitor issues, but I don't receive any performance reports.
I added this snippet codes at the end of index.php but it didn't work.

```
\Sentry\init([
    'dsn' => 'SENTRY_DSN',
    'traces_sampler' => static function (\Sentry\Tracing\SamplingContext $context): float {
        if (false !== strpos($context->getTransactionContext()->getName(), 'health')) {
            // Discard transactions that have 'health' in their name
            return 0.0;
        }
        // Sample rate for all other transactions
        return 1.0;
    },
]);
```

Can anyone help me to configure wordpress to use performance monitoring in sentry?

Comment: Please add any specifics to the question itself. If those links gets removed/that site goes down, the question won't make sense anymore. If the question is how to use a specific plugin, or that it doesn't work as expected, you should rather contact the developers that made it than us since this isn't a generic support site for third party plugins.

Comment: Hi Magnus, I tried to correct the question. It's not relevant to the wordpress plugin. wordpress needs to be configured to send performance reports to sentry.

Answer (score 2):

You should add it as a mu-plugin because of the Wordpress firing order: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

I’ve managed to have *some* functionality going by integrating with the wp-sentry plugin with a custom mu-plugin. Check my answer here, may get better over time: https://github.com/stayallive/wp-sentry/issues/68

Install wp-sentry plugin and add this to a file inside /wp-content/mu-plugins. Make sure to remove the mu-plugin for wp-sentry before.

```php
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: WordPress Sentry
 * Plugin URI: https://github.com/stayallive/wp-sentry
 * Description: A (unofficial) WordPress plugin to report PHP and JavaScript errors to Sentry.
 * Version: must-use-proxy
 * Author: 
 * Author URI: 
 * License: MIT
 */
$wp_sentry = __DIR__ . '/../plugins/wp-sentry-integration/wp-sentry.php';
$ok = true;
if (!file_exists($wp_sentry)) {
    trigger_error('Sentry is not being mu-loaded because the plugin files are not there');
    $ok = false;
    return;
}

require $wp_sentry;
if(!function_exists('wp_sentry_safe') || !$ok){
    trigger_error('Sentry is not being mu-loaded because the require statement failed');
    return;
}

define( 'WP_SENTRY_MU_LOADED', true );

/*
 * Sentry performance activation for wordpress
 */
$sentryDsn = defined('WP_SENTRY_DSN') && (WP_SENTRY_DSN !== false);
$sentryTracingRate = defined('WP_SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE') ? WP_SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE : false;
if ($sentryDsn && is_numeric($sentryTracingRate) && $sentryTracingRate != 0) {
    # 1 - set up tracing in our hub
    wp_sentry_safe(function (\Sentry\State\HubInterface $sentryHub) {
        $rate = WP_SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE ?? 0;
        $sentryHub->getClient()->getOptions()->setTracesSampleRate($rate);
        \Sentry\SentrySdk::setCurrentHub($sentryHub);
    });
    # 2 set up transaction context

    $transactionContext = new \Sentry\Tracing\TransactionContext();

    $url = null;
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?? null) {
        $url = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php') !== false) {
            $actionName = $_GET['action'] ?? $_POST['action'] ?? 'SENTRY_PARSE_ERROR_NO_ACTION';
            /**
             * If its admin ajax, the transaction name includes the name of the action instad of the URL.
             */
            $name = "admin-ajax: ".$actionName;
            $transactionContext->setTags(['admin-ajax']);

        } else {
            $name = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
            $transactionContext->setTags(['normal-request']);
        }
    } else {
        if (defined('DOING_CRON')) {
            $name = 'cron';
            $transactionContext->setTags(['cron']);
        } else {
            $commands = $_SERVER['argv'] ?? ['','SENTRY_PARSE_ERROR_NO_COMMAND'];
            array_shift($commands); // the first one is the wp binary.
            $command = implode(' ',$commands);
            $name = 'wp '.$command;
            $transactionContext->setTags(['wp-cli']);
        }
    }
    # 3 set up transaction context
    $transactionContext->setName($name);
    $transactionContext->setOp('http.server');
    $transactionContext->setData([
        'url' => $url,
        'method' => strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ?? '')
    ]);
    $transactionContext->setStartTimestamp($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] ?? microtime(true) );

    # 4 start transaction
    $transaction = \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->startTransaction($transactionContext);
    \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($transaction);

    # 5 set up span context
    $spanContext = new \Sentry\Tracing\SpanContext();
    $spanContext->setOp('wordpress_span');
    $spanContext->setStartTimestamp(microtime(true));

    # 6 start span
    $appSpan = $transaction->startChild($spanContext);
    //$appSpan->getTraceContext() this?
    \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($appSpan);

    add_action('shutdown', function () {
        # 7 finish span
        $sentrySpan = \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->getSpan();
        if($sentrySpan){
            $sentrySpan->finish();
        }
        $sentryTransaction = \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->getTransaction();
        # 8 finish transaction
        if($sentryTransaction){
            \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($sentryTransaction);
            $transaction = \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->getSpan();
            $transaction->finish();
        }
    });
}
```

After adding it, make sure to define WP_SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE in wp-config.php with a value between 0 and 1. 0,3 for production is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this! Regarding the intermediary spans to identify which hooks or db queries are slow, I wonder if one could reuse the code from the WP CLI "profile"plugin: https://github.com/wp-cli/profile-command